# Unable to insert Cell to UITableView even updating DataSource before using insertRowsAtIndexPaths method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to add a new cell below the tapped cell on the event tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

These are my numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection methods. The property self.dataTable is the datasource of my TableView.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //i have that - 1 there because i don't want to use the first row of my dataTable.
    //On my cellForRowAtIndex method I'm adding a +1 to the indexPath.row to get the right row information
    return [self.dataTable count] - 1;
}
```

My adding method is:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableArray * newRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Columna 1", @"Columna 2", @"Columna 3", @"Columna 4", nil];
    //here im adding the new item to the datasource.
    [self.dataTable insertObject:newRow atIndex:indexPath.row + 1];                       

    NSArray *newData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row + 1) inSection:1], nil];
    //self because this clas inherits from UITableView and implements its own delegate and datasource.
    //The error is also produced using tableView instead of self.
    [self beginUpdates];

    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newData withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

    [self endUpdates];

}
```

When the debbugger reach [self endUpdates], the methos numberOfRowsInSection is launched and I can see the return is updated with +1, however im getting this error:

> Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.

Edit: Adding cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"SWTableCell";

UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    UILabel *lblTemp; //Used for creates labels for cell
    CGRect readjust, rectTemp;
    rectTemp = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 15); //Size of the cell


    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.frame = rectTemp;

    int x = 10; //initial x position for each label
    for(int i = 0; i < self.columnCount; i++)
    {
        rectTemp = CGRectMake(x, 10, COLUMN_WIDTH, 20); //Size of each column

        lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectTemp]; //inicialize label
        lblTemp.tag = i;
        [lblTemp setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        lblTemp.text = (NSString *)[[dataTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1] objectAtIndex:i];
        lblTemp.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        [lblTemp setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        if(i!=0) lblTemp.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        else lblTemp.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

            lblTemp.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
            [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        [lblTemp setNumberOfLines:1];
        [lblTemp sizeToFit];

        readjust = lblTemp.frame;
        readjust = CGRectMake(readjust.origin.x, readjust.origin.y, COLUMN_WIDTH, readjust.size.height);
        lblTemp.frame = readjust;


        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];
        [lblTemp release];

        x = x + COLUMN_WIDTH;
    }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

What else can be causing this issue?

Comment: can you show us the `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataTable count] - 1;
}
```

should be

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataTable count];
}
```

the found or length of an collection is the number of items it is containing. only indexing start with 0. So if you have put 5 items in an array, it has count 5, while the last item's index is 4.

Now I have been blind as well:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //…
    [self beginUpdates];
    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newData withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self endUpdates];
}
```

must be

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //…
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newData withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: You are right, however, i have that - 1 there because i don't want to use the first row of my dataTable. On my cellForRowAtIndex method I'm adding a +1 to the indexPath.row to get the right row information. I will update the question.

Comment: if you mean, that you don't want to use the first cell, than it must be +1

Comment: I use -1 because the first row doesn't count. On the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I'm using indexRow.row +1. My cellForRowAtIndexPath is kind of messy, however I will add it to the question.

Comment: what do u mean with row? if it is the first cell of the tableView, it has to be +1, if you don't want to use the first item in you array, it should be -1. or you should remove it.

Comment: Don't want to use the first item in my array, so It's -1. For the future conversation row = array, cell = tableview.

Comment: I don't get you edit. What do you mean with "Now I have been blind as well" Excuse me but English is not my native language, just learning it. I was using self because my class is a UITableView derivate and its its own delegate and datasource. I did the change, same error message.

Comment: Sounds like very bad design. If you subclass UITableView you must run into problems, as you don't know the internals, it is executing. You don't know, when to call a super's method from within the overwritten on — or if you have to call it at all. This is the problem with most UIView descendants. Instead vas your own UITableViewController subclass. this can be the datasource and delegate.

Comment: Well, i will change the design, its going to be very easy. Thanks for the help. This is my day 4 programing on objetive-c But i really need to make this insert cell work.